# How to get the count of columns with respect to their names in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am doing pre-processing of data and managing missing values.I want to set the threshold on columns.For a single column, if the value count is less than 50,then drop the column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv('cbc_updated_1.csv')
```

Then I get column counts.

```
a = df.count(axis = 0)
print(a)
```

It gives the column names with respect to their counts.

```
IP ABN(RBC)RET Abn Scattergram       46
IP ABN(RBC)Reticulocytosis           23
IP ABN(PLT)Thrombocytosis            47
IP ABN(PLT)PLT Abn Scattergram        0
IP SUS(WBC)Blasts?                   57
IP SUS(WBC)Abn Lympho?               10
IP SUS(WBC)Left Shift?              190
IP SUS(WBC)Atypical Lympho?         126
IP SUS(RBC)RBC Agglutination?         0
IP SUS(RBC)Turbidity/HGB Interf?      9
IP SUS(RBC)Iron Deficiency?          27
IP SUS(RBC)HGB Defect?                3
IP SUS(RBC)Fragments?               168
IP SUS(PLT)PLT Clumps?               73
dtype: int64
```

Next i want to run loop on above data to check my threshold condition...
But I am unable to do this..
I tried the following code..

```
for i in a:
    if i < 50:
        print(i)
```

In result I only got the values,not the column names.I need both.

```
46
23
47
0
10
0
9
27
3
```

How can I yield this?

Comment: can you give an example of `cbc_updated_1.csv` before the manipulation and after the manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
>>> a[a < 50]
IP ABN(RBC)RET Abn Scattergram      46
IP ABN(RBC)Reticulocytosis          23
IP ABN(PLT)Thrombocytosis           47
IP ABN(PLT)PLT Abn Scattergram       0
IP SUS(WBC)Abn Lympho?              10
IP SUS(RBC)RBC Agglutination?        0
IP SUS(RBC)Turbidity/HGB Interf?     9
IP SUS(RBC)Iron Deficiency?         27
IP SUS(RBC)HGB Defect?               3
dtype: int64
>>>
```

If you want a loop:

```
for x in a[a < 50].reset_index().to_numpy().tolist():
    print(*x)
```

---

```
IP ABN(RBC)RET Abn Scattergram 46
IP ABN(RBC)Reticulocytosis 23
IP ABN(PLT)Thrombocytosis 47
IP ABN(PLT)PLT Abn Scattergram 0
IP SUS(WBC)Abn Lympho? 10
IP SUS(RBC)RBC Agglutination? 0
IP SUS(RBC)Turbidity/HGB Interf? 9
IP SUS(RBC)Iron Deficiency? 27
IP SUS(RBC)HGB Defect? 3
```